# How i may get the complete jQuery UI icon list [icon css-class] - [icon]

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JQuery UI has a lot of different icons(`ui-icon-info`, `ui-icon-circle-close`, `ui-icon-document` etc) how or where i may get/view the complete list of that?
It would be to have it like that: [icon css-class] - [icon vew]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/) is a cheatsheet that shows them all :)

Answer (score 4):

The whole list is available (with previews) in [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Hover over an icon to see its class name in a tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

[You can check that out here.](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Answer (score 0):

Just look in the css. Or look in the images file to see it all.